# How to remove blank space in the starting of every line in crystal report 9 during export to text format

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Detail section as one formula by combining required fields in it,
example of Detail formula (using `Chr(9)` for tab spacing between each field, so that exporting in text would be usable by Mainframe job),

```
{AccountPool.Name} & Chr(9)  &
{@Currency}  & Chr(9)  &
{Company.Name}  & Chr(9)  &
{@AcctNum_300000or30002}  & Chr(9)  &
{@AcctNum_30001} & Chr(9)  &
{Account.PoolSide}
```

Similarly in header also I am using single formula in same way with different text fields.

Issue is, while exporting report to Text format, I am getting a blank space before every line (except header line).

Answer (score 0):

CR will try to preserve the layout of the fields when exporting to text, so if you're seeing white space at the beginning of each line it's because the fields are not flush against the page edge on that side. You can try to move the fields left as far as you can.

Instead, though, I'd recommend you place the fields into the report in the order you want them (not concatenated together in one big formula) and then export it as tab-separated-values, which will strip all the formatting from the report and make it much friendlier to machine read.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i need it to use in concatenated due to teh fact of Tab seperation between fields. Also, regarding length for concatenated field in report format is streched till last in Landscape A3 page

Comment: @Thunder-Bolt Exporting as a tab-separated-values automatically inserts the tabs between fields and it also completely disregards page size.

Comment: you are right, but in tab seperated there will be quotes symbol (") before and after every field data

Comment: @Thunder-Bolt The fields will only be quote-delimited if that is the format you choose to export it in. There is no rule that says that you have to use delimiters at all, so you can just as easily export a tab-separated file with no quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
but, i have tried in the thrid party tool whic will use this RPT to generate report, and its not working. I will do some more R&D to check if i can manage to get in crystal and then it can reflect in third party reporting tool.